# Microsoft Graph API - Outlook - Get all members from an organisation

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API to get information from outlook. Currently my GET returns all groups within my organisation, and from there I can get members from each specific group using the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{ID}/members`

I am wondering if I am able to get all members from all groups eg. All members with the email ending @myCompany.co.uk?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/v1.0/users` endpoint will return all user's in the tenant.